# $p$-adic Integration

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I am struggling to compute the following integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{Z}_p}\exp_p(|x|_p)d\mu
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\exp_p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} \text{ defined on } |x|_p<p^{-1/(p-1)}
\end{equation}
I know that in general
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{Z}_p}f(|x|_p)d\mu=(1-p^{-1})\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}f(p^{-i})p^{-i}
\end{equation}
but I am confused by the limited domain of $\exp_p(x)$. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, $\exp_p(p^{-0})$ doesn't seem to make sense. Are you sure we aren't viewing $\exp$ as a completely real-valued function for this integral? (The integrand in $p$-adic integration need not have codomain the $p$-adics.) Even then, I don't immediately see a nice closed-form. It might also help to cite the source of the problem.

Comment: This was an integral I thought up myself, it wasn't taken from a textbook and I was just curious as to whether it could be solved. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Your integral for a function from $\mathbb Z_p$ into $\mathbb Q_p$. Are you sure there exists such type of integral?